# Android: bug using Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_HDR on HTC One X

Tags: java, android, crash, camera

I have to use the scene HDR on my application. This option is available since the android version 4.2 so it should be available on the HTC One X. However my app crashes when I launch it. I tried this code and it worked on an acer with Android 4.2.1. I use a surfaceView to display the preview. Here is the code I use :

```
private void setParameters(){

    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_HDR );
    camera.setParameters(params);
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

    camera = Camera.open();  
    try {  
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); 
        setParameters();

    } catch (IOException exception) {  
        camera.release();  
        camera = null;  
    }  
}
```

Here is the Log :

```
10-18 16:11:13.486: E/(24770): file /data/data/com.nvidia.NvCPLSvc/files/driverlist.txt: not found!
10-18 16:11:13.486: I/(24770): Attempting to load EGL implementation /system/lib//egl/libEGL_tegra_impl
10-18 16:11:13.491: I/(24770): Loaded EGL implementation /system/lib//egl/libEGL_tegra_impl
10-18 16:11:13.516: I/(24770): Loading GLESv2 implementation /system/lib//egl/libGLESv2_tegra_impl
10-18 16:11:13.801: W/dalvikvm(24770): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f7aa08)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1588)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at com.hologram.camerarv.CamerarvSurfaceView.setParameters(CamerarvSurfaceView.java:98)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at com.hologram.camerarv.CamerarvSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(CamerarvSurfaceView.java:183)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:569)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:174)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:680)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2156)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1190)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4860)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:766)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:575)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:542)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:751)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
10-18 16:11:13.806: E/AndroidRuntime(24770):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From official docs:

> Different devices may have different camera capabilities, such as picture size or flash modes. The application should query the camera capabilities before setting parameters. For example, the application should call getSupportedColorEffects() before calling setColorEffect(String). If the camera does not support color effects, getSupportedColorEffects() will return null.

Try checking if that device supports HDR mode first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your were right , this phone don't support the scene HDR with the function setSceneMode. But I can use this scene with the native camera app. So do you know if there is a way to use it?

Comment: Hmm, this might be hard as it's a properiary software probably. Sadly I have no idea. Remember to mark answer as accepted!